# Issue With Writing SUMIF via VBA That References Multiple Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, syntax, excel-formula

I am attempting to write the following formula to the "Order Number" Worksheet (in column CL) via VBA:
`=SUMIF('Dummy Sheet One'!C:C,'Order Number'!DB3,'Dummy Sheet One'!A:A)`

The formula works as expected when typed into a cell on the sheet itself and is dragged down.

I have attempted several different bits of code:

Attempt One:

```
Dim wsDummy As WorksheetDummy Sheet One")

Dim wsOrderNumber As Worksheet
Set wsOrderNumber = Worksheets("Order Number")

wsOrderNumber.Cells(2, 90).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF('" & wsDummy.Name & "'!C:C," & wsOrderNumber.Name & "'!DB2""," & wsDummy.Name & "!A:A)"
```

This gives me an "application or object defined" error.

Attempt Two:

```
Dim wsDummy As Worksheet
Set wsDummy = Worksheets("Dummy Sheet One")

Dim wsOrderNumber As Worksheet
Set wsOrderNumber = Worksheets("Order Number")

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Worksheets("Order Number").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

worksheets("Order Number").Range(“CL2”) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(wsDummy.Range(“C:C"), wsOrderNumber.range(DB2), wsDummy.Range("A:A"))
Worksheets("Order Number").Range(.Cells(2, 90), .Cells(LastRow, 90)).FillDown
```

This gives me an "Invalid or unqualified reference" error.

I am guessing I am missing something like a set of quotation marks or have some other syntax related issue?  I have looked on this site and online and can't find anything to set me straight.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a typo at the end of the line of your first code block? The double quote and close parentheses look wrong.

Comment: Attempt 1: Missing opening single quote before `wsOrderNumber.Name`, and both quotes around the second `wsDummy.Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem might be a mix of quotes and wrong object.

1. I've fixed your dimensioning
2. I've changed the object reference from `FormulaR1C1` to `Formula`
3. I've changed the quotes in the formula (there were extra double quotes)

   ```
   Dim wsDummy As Worksheet
   Set wsDummy = Worksheets("Dummy Sheet One")

   Dim wsOrderNumber As Worksheet
   Set wsOrderNumber = Worksheets("Order Number")

   wsOrderNumber.Cells(2, 90).Formula = "=SUMIF('" & wsDummy.Name & "'!C:C,'" & wsOrderNumber.Name & "'!DB2,'" & wsDummy.Name & "'!A:A)"
   ```

A good way to check your formulas, is to put a watch on the line that's erroring out, and paste the string into the debug / immediate pane like this:

```
?"=SUMIF('" & wsDummy.Name & "'!C:C,'" & wsOrderNumber.Name & "'!DB2,'" & wsDummy.Name & "'!A:A)"
```

It's helpful for debugging confusing strings like this.

Comment: I tried as you suggested and placed that line into the immediate window and it said "Expected Expression"  -- How would you utilize that to find the issue with the extra quotes?

Comment: Good question - I usually paste it in bit by bit, until you find where the error lies. Making sure that the bit you're pasting has a double quote at the beginning and end, it should work... Sometimes though, it's just checking that each quote that is opened, is closed where it's meant to  be, and checking that everything between gives you the results that you want (ie. pretend you're a computer, and parse the line manually)